# Open modal and then change the url without redirecting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to open a modal and change the url but stay on the same page. So it should just open a modal change the url, and then when the popup is closed it will just remove added URL.

I have a script that changes the URL on click, but if I set it on click it changes the url but the modal isn't opening. So I'm sure it needs to be done with somehow detecting if the modal is opened/closed.

**My jQuery code:**

```
 $(".modal").click(function() { 
   window.history.pushState("obj", "newtitle", "/newurl");
   return false;
 });
```

**2nd try:**

```
if ($(".feedModal").hasClass("show")) {
    window.history.pushState("obj", "newtitle", "/abc");
    return false;
});
```

I use bootstrap for modals, and I saw that I can detect the modal opening with `bs.modal.shown` but it didn't worked for me. I also tried `shown` still no help.

Any help will mean a lot. Thanks!

Comment: Can you show the code where you change the url?

Comment: @MariosNikolaou `history.pushState` will update the navigation bar (without causing a redirect or reload). See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState

Comment: The Emiel's second answer helped me. Thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code suggests that you click on the `$(".feedModal")` element to open or close the modal. If that is not the case, then this can be easily modified. This will help you on your way though.

Check in the click event on the trigger if the modal is already visible with the *psuedo-selector* `:visible`. If it is hide it with the `.modal('hide')` method of a [Bootstrap Modal](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/). This will hide it and trigger an event which we'll use later. If it is not visible, show it with `.modal('show')`.

```js
var $modal = $('.feedModal');
var $modal.on('click', function(event) {
    if ($modal.is(':visible')) {
        $modal.modal('hide');
    } else {
        $modal.modal('show');
    }
});
```

We can listen on the modal if it is opened or closed with the `show.bs.modal` and `hide.bs.modal` event handlers. By listening when the modal opens we change the history to the new value. And by listening when the modal closes we change it back to the previous state.

```
var $feedModal = $('#feedModal');

// Listen for modal hide and popstate events.
function startListening() {
    $feedModal.on('hide.bs.modal', onModalHide);
    $(window).on('popstate', onPopState);
}

// Stop listening for modal hide and popstate events.
function stopListening() {
    $feedModal.off('hide.bs.modal', onModalHide);
    $(window).off('popstate', onPopState);
}

// Modal opens.
// Add event listeners and push state.
function onModalShow() {
    startListening();
    window.history.pushState({}, '', '/abc');
}

// Modal hides.
// Remove event listeners and go back.
function onModalHide() {
    stopListening();
    window.history.back();
}

// Navigation occurs.
// Remove event listeners and hide modal.
function onPopState() {
    stopListening();
    $feedModal.modal('hide');
}

// Listen for when the modal shows.
$feedModal.on('show.bs.modal', onModalShow);
```

Comment: Man you are a genius! Thanks so much second option helped.

Comment: this works great, but when a user hits the back button it does not close the modal, just changes the URL. Then when the user realizes they have to close the modal manually, they do, and THEN the back-button event happens again, bringing the user TWO urls back...

Comment: seems the back button should the close modal if it's going to change the url as well

Comment: @ShawnT, thanks for the feedback. I've added a popstate listener which closes the modal when the added state is popped, like when clicking the back button.

Comment: sorry for the game of whack-a-mole but now that i play a little more, with the popstate function in there, it closes the modal AND goes back 2 URLs instead of 1

Comment: No worries, it should be correct for others like yourself. I've added a flag which will be changed on popstate, preventing `window.history.back()` being called when using browser navigation. Should work properly.

Comment: @ShawnT The previous solution also had a flaw which prevented navigating back. I've changed the approach by adding and removing event listeners after navigation or closing of the modal preventing from any triggers to fire after one another.

Comment: that did i! i wish I could give it two upvotes now :)